# Convert private SSL certificate to PKCS12 format for JKS Keystore

Tags: tls, openssl

I got the following files from company certificate provider.

```
jenkins.int.XX.com.key
XX_Inc_Private_Root_CA.base64.cer
XX_Inc_Private_Root_CA.crt
XX_Inc_Private_SSL_CA.509.cer
XX_Inc_Private_SSL_CA.509.pem
```

Here is the two commands I run to convert:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out jenkins_keystore.p12 -passout 'pass:changeit' -inkey jenkins.int.xx.com.key -in XX_Inc_Private_Root_CA.base64.cer
 error message: No certificate matches private key


 openssl pkcs12 -export -out jenkins_keystore.p12 -passout 'pass:changeit' -inkey jenkins.int.xx.com.key -in XX_Inc_Private_SSL_CA.509.cer
 error message: unable to load certificates
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Based on the file names and the openssl output you have the certificates for the cert-chain, but you miss the certificate that belongs to the jenkins key file.

Comment: I agree with @Robert that the names make it look like your jenkins key is missing its certificate.  As written, your commands would not return errors if you replaced the .cer files with the correct certificate associated with the key.  Check with your company's certificate provider and see if they can provide you with the appropriate certificate file.